# Strange quotes in meta values in haxe?

Tags: haxe

I have this simple code to extract meta values from class:

```
package;

@:rtti
class TestClass
{
    @testMeta("test_val_0", "test_val_1")
    var testVar = 0;
}

class Main
{
    static function main()
    {
        trace(haxe.rtti.Meta.getFields(TestClass).testVar.testMeta[0]);
        for( field in haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(TestClass).fields )
            if( field.name == "testVar" )
                for( meta in field.meta )
                    if( meta.name == "testMeta" )
                        trace(meta.params[0]);
    }
}
```

When I compile and run it I get this strange results:

```
c:\test_meta>haxe -main Main -neko test.n & neko test.n
Main.hx:14: test_val_0
Main.hx:19: "test_val_0"
```

Are this results ok or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong as far as I can tell, and this is definitely a strange discrepancy.

I just tested this with the latest development branch of Haxe, and the behavior is identical there. I'd create an issue on [Haxe's issue tracker](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues) to let the Haxe team know about this potential bug.